# How to compare sequence of two string array

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-2.0

I have two string array

```
string[] a; 
string[] b;
```

How can I find that the sequence of element in array a is similar to array b?

As I am using .net2.0 I can't use LINQ.

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried

```
foreach (string val2 in a)
                { 
                                       foreach (string val1 in b)
                    {
                        if (val1 == val2)
                        {
                           // Values are same - continue processing
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Value not same   -- exit                         }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What exactly is the `sequence of element' ?

Comment: Define similar.  Are you looking for identical matches between the same indexes in each array?

Comment: Show an example of what you have and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to see if the elements in both arrays have **same value and on same index**. You can have a simple method like:

```
public static bool IsSequenceEqual(string[] a, string[] b)
{
    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    private bool Compare(string[] a, string[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i< a.Length; i++)
            if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If both lists are sorted you can use one of the other solutions. But if the lists are unsorted you could do the following.

```
  Dictionary<string, byte> dict = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
  foreach (string s in a)
  {
      dict.Add(s, 0);
  }

  bool same = true;
  foreach (string s in b)
  {
      same &= dict.ContainsKey(s);
      if (!same) 
          break;
  }
```

You could still do simple test before this like check for equal length and such.

If you could use .NET 4.0 there's the `Intersect` method for arrays.
You can then do `a.Intersect(b)` and compare the length with the length of `a` or `b`. If that is `true` then the lists are equal because all the elements of both arrays intersect. You can do a similar trick with `a.Union(b)`.

**EDIT**
Use Dictionary instead of ArrayList as suggested by phoog.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` rather than `List<string>`?  Regardless, `Contains` is O(n) on lists; if the lists are large, you're better off using a `HashSet<>`, where `Contains` is O(1).  (`HashSet<>` was introduced in .NET 3.5, so for .NET 2.0 or 3.0, you can use `Dictionary<string, byte>`, ignoring the values, and using `ContainsKey` instead of `Contains`.)

Comment: I've quickly implemented you suggestions. It's been a long time since I had to do anything in .NET 2.0 so I don't remember every thing we do and do not have. Obviously, you can do a lot better with a newer version of .NET.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two string array. 
    ///  If both null - return true ; 
    ///  If only one is null - return false ;
    /// </summary>
    bool IsSequenceEqual(string[] a, string[] b)
    {
        if (a == null && b == null) // both null - return true
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null) // only one is null - return false
            return false;

        if (a.Length != b.Length) // length is different - return false
            return false;

        // check if equal
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```